# Europa's beautiful pair

Tags: riddle, knowledge, geography

> Europa's endowed with a beautiful pair,
>   Between them some stunning Bavarian flair.
>   If you love nice châteaux, hands up in the air,
>   Surrender completely to Brittany fair.
>
> A volatile border's now marked by a bug,
>   A former pole's become a prominent hub.
>   A trial site's FC's boys take pride in their club,
>   Hey, pour me a pint in that old Frankish pub!

What pair is being referred to? What's in the middle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

@gearstache had the answer, I think (full credit to him!):

> Brest, France and Brest, Belarus; with Nuremburg, Germany in between...@jafe that's some cheeky wordplay...

but it's disappeared and I don't know where it went!

Here are the explanations:

Europa's endowed with a beautiful pair, 
Between them some stunning Bavarian flair.

> The Bavarian flair between them refers to Nuremburg

If you love nice châteaux, hands up in the air, 
Surrender completely to Brittany fair.

> Brest is in Brittany, and Brittany is in France and has chateaux...also please no [France surrendering jokes!](https://www.reddit.com/r/OutOfTheLoop/comments/2syolf/why_is_everyone_at_rmurica_making_jokes_about/)

A volatile border's now marked by a bug,

> The Bug River separates Belarus from Poland...ie. Poland from the former Soviet Union.

A former pole's become a prominent hub.

> The city of Brest was formerly Polish, but is now in Belarus.

A trial site's FC's boys take pride in their club, 
Hey, pour me a pint in that old Frankish pub!

> Refers to [1. FC Nuremberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1._FC_N%C3%BCrnberg) and the Nuremberg Trials!

Comment: Very close, looking for something a bit more specific. Line 6 doesn't really fit, does it?

Comment: I learned something new about European geography today! I think Line 6 fits better now, @jafe

Comment: This is very close, but not the intended answer. The pair I'm looking for has an even more obvious connection.

Comment: The only obvious connections I can think of seem to be stretches...this is a fun thinker though! :)

Comment: Augh, think I may have failed in locating the middle point... Your previous answer had the middle right, at least that's what the clues point at. Looking at the map again it does seem the new answer is closer to the geographic middle...

Comment: That's what I figured, Frankfurt is in Hesse rather than Bavaria...there's probably a route on Google Maps that went through the middle you were hinting at instead! Is this correct? (Also, well played with this puzzle, very cheeky indeed @jafe )

Comment: Yeah, all three are correct with the right explanations. You get the tick!

Comment: 7 hours later, I learned another new thing haha, I only thought Europe had the western one (never knew about the other one!) Thanks very much! Great puzzle! :)

Answer (score 7):

Europa's endowed with a beautiful pair,
Between them some stunning Bavarian flair.

> The pair is **Orléans** in France and **Krakow** in Poland, with **Nuremberg** in Germany in between. All three are twin (or triplet?) cities.

If you love nice châteaux, hands up in the air,
Surrender completely to Brittany fair.

> **Orléans** is in the Loire region, known for its châteaux. The city itself is not in Brittany, but the Loire flows into the Atlantic in Brittany.

A volatile border's now marked by a bug,
A former pole's become a prominent hub.

> **Krakow**'s airport ius named after former Pope John Paul II, who was Polish. El-Guest has already found out that the Bug is a river in the border reghion of Poland, Ukraine and Belarus. Eventually, the Bug flows into the Vistula, which passes through Krakow.

A trial site's FC's boys take pride in their club,
Hey, pour me a pint in that old Frankish pub!

> Al El-Guest already mentioned, 1. FC Nürnberg, or just "the Club" to its supporters, has just been promoted. **Nuremberg**, the site of the Nuremberg trials (and of the Nuremberg rallies before that), is in the state of Bavaria, whose norhern region is Francinia. (And I thought the adjective should be Franconian instead of Frankish?)

Comment: I really like this answer too!! I hadn't considered the r13(gjva pvgvrf) aspect; just the literal meaning of between instead. (+1) from me!

Comment: This is very close, but not the intended answer. The pair I'm looking for has an even more obvious connection.

Comment: Hmm. I guess Orléans is the one that is still wrong. I see no obvious connection, except that both [Krakow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krakowska) and [Nuremberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bratwurst) are known for their sausages.

Answer (score 2):

the pair:

> Brest France and Brest Belarus

what's in the middle:

> Frankfurt

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE. Can you explain your answer, please?